# Marking a TODO item DONE does not create a CLOSING timestamp in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I'm following this tutorial:

https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/orgtutorial_dto.html

```
* Tasks
** DONE start a new org file for tutorial
C-c C-t
```

modifies the second to line

```
** DONE start a new org file for tutorial
```

but is not followed by the expected

```
CLOSED <timestamp>
```

What to do?[image]

UPDATE #1:

here's how .emacs.d/init.el is setup:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(require 'org)
(define-key global-map "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(define-key global-map "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(setq org-log-done t)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `(setq org-log-done 'time)`.

Comment: In place or following `(setq org-log-done t)`? I tried both and it doesn't generate a timestamp. Also, C-x C-s does not save the task.

Comment: I assumed that `org-log-done` would be nil (default), so it's not the point. Anyway, my `emacs -Q` with your init setup works as expected...

Comment: I tried again and it worked with your solution.

Comment: Subsidiary question: how to do I close without a timestamp with the new setup?

Comment: Without setting org-log-done, timestamp will not be created when closing. It's default behavior. To ensure, you may explicitly set `(setq org-log-done nil)`.