# Marking a TODO item DONE with or without a timestamp

Tags: org-mode

it was established in a [previous post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47951/marking-a-todo-item-done-does-not-create-a-closing-timestamp-in-org-mode) that `(setq org-log-done 'time)` should be substituted for `(setq org-log-done t)` in the init file, so that C-c C-t would close a TODO *with* a timestamp. I would like to be able to choose between closing *with or without* a timestamp. How, please?

This is the current setup:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(require 'org)
(define-key global-map "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)
(define-key global-map "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
  ;;(setq org-log-done t)
(setq org-log-done 'time)
;; Conventional selection/deletion 
(setq org-support-shift-select t)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `org-todo` command documentation indicates that various prefix arguments can be used to influence the behavior. I thought perhaps this was what you wanted:

```
With a numeric prefix arg of 0, inhibit note taking for the change.
```

However, that doesn't seem to work for `'time`.

You can create your own command that overrides the `org-log-done` setting, and bind it to some other key. Here's an example: this will run when `org` is loaded, define a variant of the `org-todo` command, and bind it to `C-c C-S-t`:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org

    (defun my-org-todo-quietly ()
      (interactive)
      (let ((org-log-done nil))
        (org-todo)))

  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-S-t") 'my-org-todo-quietly))
```

You should then be able to use `C-c C-t` for the default behavior with the timestamp, or `C-c C-S-t` to skip the timestamp.

Comment: Where is the key?

Comment: Is `C-S-t` `Ctrl-shift-t` or `Ctrl-upper case s-t`? Neither works. `Ctrl-uc S` invokes `schedule`.

Comment: `C-S-t` is Ctrl-Shift-t. You can use a different key if you prefer, that one worked for me and seemed like a logical variant of the default C-c C-t.

Comment: Probably because I did not close the file (is there a way to reload init?), now I did and it worked, thank you.

Comment: Subsidiary question: `M-x describe-key C-c C-t` says `C-c C-t` not defined. It is defined.

Comment: Did you try describe-key from an org-mode buffer? That key is defined in a mode map so it will not be active unless you are currently in org-mode. You may want to take a look at the Emacs manual (which can be read within Emacs -- try `C-h r` to open it). See `Evaluating Emacs Lisp Expressions` for how to evaluate some new code in your init file without restarting; and `Customizing Key Bindings` for more on key maps.